# Form and Tags with website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built a web page with tags using js and css, but now  other tags are in color when I click next tags could anybody help me? Thanks a looooooooooot. I dont want other tags change color when I click another tag~

```js
        function show(e, n) {
     var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    
        // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("rcContent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    
        // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
    
        // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened   the tab
        document.getElementById(n).style.display = "block";
        e.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
```

```css
   .rcTab{
     list-style: none;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 2px 8px;
     margin: 0 5px;
     background: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 2px;
     background-color: #aaa;
     color: white;
    }
    .rcTab:hover{
     background-color:#cd2027;
    }
    
    .rcTab.active {
     background-color: #cd2027; /*url("http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/themes/shaver/img/bkg-redlines.png");*/
    
    }
    .rcContent {
     display: none;
    }
    
    .rcContent h4 {
     //transform: translate(50%, 0);
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .rc {
     list-style-image: url('http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/document-e1481910868320.png');
     background: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     margin-left: 40px
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <ul class="rcTabs" id="Tabs">
     <li class="rcTab active" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show(event,'rcContent1');">Literature</li>
     <li class="rcTab" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show(event,'rcContent2');">Case Studies</li>
     <li class="rcTab" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show(event,'rcContent3');">Technical Data Sheets</li>
    </ul>
    <div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 10px 5px;">
    <div id="rcContent1" class="rcContent" style="display: block;">
    <h4>Curtains &amp; Dividers</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Curtain-Walls-General-web1.pdf">Curtains &amp; Dividers Brochure</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SW-C100Curtain-Wall-Auto-.pdf">Curtain Wall - Automative</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Curtain-vs.-Perm.-Wall-.pdf">Curtain Wall vs. Permanent Wall</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SW-I200InsulWall-Brochure-WEB.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall Brochure</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Building-Green-InsulWall.pdf" target="_blank">Green InsulWall</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Roll-Up Doors</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/G2-Lite-Doors-NEW-o.pdf">G2 Lite Series</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/G2-5400-Series-NEW-o.pdf">G2 5400 Series</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>PVC Strip Curtains</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-010-Truck-Strip-Curtains.pdf" target="_blank">Rear PVC Strip Door System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Noise Control Solutions</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-001-Compressor-Enclosure-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Compressor Enclosure</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Welding Protection</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Swing Doors</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SD-001-400-Series-Swing-Door.pdf" target="_blank">400 Series Swing Door</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SD-002-700-Series-Swing-Door.pdf" target="_blank">700 Series Swing Door</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SD-003-1000-Series-Swing-Door.pdf" target="_blank">1000 Series Swing Door</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Truck Curtains, Insulated Bulkheads &amp; Dividers</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-001-BH200-Bulkheads.pdf" target="_blank">High Performance BH2000 Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-002-Light-Weight-CoolGaurd.pdf" target="_blank">Lightweight Series CoolGuard Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-003-Delivery-Van-Bulkhead.pdf" target="_blank">Delivery Van Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-004-VersaFit-Bulkhead.pdf" target="_blank">VersaFit Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-005-Z-Shape-Bulkhead.pdf" target="_blank">Z-Shaped Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-007-Quick-Release-Truck-Curtain.pdf" target="_blank">Quick Release Rear Door Curtain</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-008-Roller-Curtain.pdf" target="_blank">Rear Roller Curtain</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-009-Gravity-Door-Curtain.pdf" target="_blank">Side Door Gravity Curtain</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-010-Truck-Strip-Curtains.pdf" target="_blank">Rear PVC Strip Door System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-006-Center-Divide-System.pdf" target="_blank">Center Divide System</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rcContent2" class="rcContent">
    <h4></h4>
    <h4>Curtains &amp; Dividers</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/whats-behind-your-curtain-wall/" target="_blank">What’s Behind Your Curtain Wall?</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/facility-operations-wall/" target="_blank">Facility Operations: More Than a Wall</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-custom-curtains-protect-print-press-from-dust-and-debris/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Custom Curtains Protect Print Press From Dust and Debris</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Insulated Curtains (InsulWall)</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SW-I900-InsulWall-Beer-CS-Press.pdf" target="_blank">Beer Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Berries-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Berries Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Cheese-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Cheese Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Chocolate-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Chocolate Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Data-Center-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Date Centre Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Farm-Fresh-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Farm Fresh Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Floral-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Floral Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SW-1800-InsullWall-Ice-Cream-CS-.pdf" target="_blank">Ice Cream Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-M-Block-CS-Low-Res.pdf" target="_blank">M Block Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Pharma-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Pharma Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Red-Bull-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Red Bull Case Study</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Noise Control Solutions</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/employee-air-conditioning-booth/" target="_blank">Employee Air Conditioning Booth</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/enclose-noisy-equipment-factory/" target="_blank">Enclose Noisy Equipment in Your Factory</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/noise-solutions-for-roof-top-hvac-units/" target="_blank">Noise Solutions For Roof Top HVAC Units</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/compressor-enclosure-for-automotive/" target="_blank">Compressor Enclosure for Automotive Dealership</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-sound-panels-work-wonders-at-stamping-plant/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Sound Panels Work Wonders at Stamping Plant</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-enclosures-reduce-compressor-noise-automotive-facility/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Enclosures Reduce Compressor Noise In Automotive Facility</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/noisy-plastic-regrind-machine-no-match-for-shavers-custom-enclosure-system/" target="_blank">Noisy Plastic Regrind Machine No Match for Shaver’s Custom Enclosure System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/noisy-compressors-no-match-for-shavers-sound-absorber-panels/" target="_blank">Noisy Compressors No Match for Shaver’s Sound Absorber Panels</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-power-roll-up-door-contains-noise-from-parts-being-dumped-into-a-hopper/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Power Roll Up Door Contains Noise From Parts Being Dumped Into a Hopper</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-noise-abatement-solutions-increase-productivity-and-safety/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Noise Abatement Solutions Increase Productivity and Safety</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shaver-helps-mining-company-increase-productivity/" target="_blank">Shaver Helps Mining Company Increase Productivity</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/power-roll-up-doors-for-food-handling-industry/" target="_blank">Power Roll Up Doors for Food Handling Industry</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-029-Case-Study-Acoustical-Curtain-Panel.pdf" target="_blank">Squealing Tires and Screeching Tires</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-030-Case-Study-Acoustical-Curtain-Panels.pdf" target="_blank">Outdoor Noise Solution</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-033-Case-Study-Acoustical-Lagging.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Lagging Quiets Perkins School For The Blind</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-034-Case-Study-Accoustical-Absorption-Barrier-Panels.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Composite Quiets Compressor Station</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-035-Case-Study-BSC-25-Absorber-Barrier-Composite.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-25 Absorber Used in Portland Meseum of Art</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-036-Case-Study-Acoustical-Lagging.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Lagging Quiets Airport HVAC System</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rcContent3" class="rcContent">
    <h4></h4>
    <h4>Track System &amp; Mounting Information</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Pan-Ceiling-Mount.pdf" target="_blank"> Pan Ceiling Mount</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Roll-TracR-Hardware-MASTER-PDF-min-1.pdf" target="_blank">Track Mounting System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Hardware-Industrial-Curtain2.pdf" target="_blank">Track Hardware Overview</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Roller-Track-Installation-Instructions1.pdf" target="_blank">Roller Track Installation Instructions</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Curtains &amp; Dividers</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/CD-001Curtain-Wall-vs.-Perm-Wall1.pdf" target="_blank">Curtain Wall Vs. Permanent Wall</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-018-R3-InsulWall-Spec.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall R3 Spec Sheet</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-018-R3-InsulWall-Spec.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall R6 Spec Sheet</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-020-R9-InsulWall-Spec.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall R9 Spec Sheet</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-021-R15-InsulWall-Spec.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall R15 Spec Sheet</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-014-InsulWall-Green-Specs-Print-20162.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall Green Spec Sheet</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Noise Control Solutions</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-004-BBC10.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-10 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-005-BBC13-revised.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-13 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-006-BBC13-2in.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-13-2" Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-007-BBC15.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-15 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-008-BBC15-2in.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-15-2" Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-009-BSC19.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-19 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-010-BSC22.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-22 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-011-BSC24.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-24 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite&gt;/a&gt;</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-012-BSC25.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-25 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-013-QFA1-.pdf" target="_blank">QFA-1 Quilted Fiberglass Absorber</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-014-QFA7.pdf" target="_blank">QFA-7 Quilted Fiberglass Absorber</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-015-QFA10.pdf" target="_blank">QFA-10 Quilted Fiberglass Absorber</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-016-QFA14.pdf" target="_blank">QFA-14 Quilted Fiberglass Absorber</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-017-Acoustical-Curtain-Systems-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Curtain Systems</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-018-Curtain-Track-Systems-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Curtain Track System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-019-Flexible-Noise-Barriers.pdf" target="_blank">Flexible Noise Barrier</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-020-Acoustical-Pipe-Duct-Lagging-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Pipe &amp; Duct Lagging</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-021-Quilted-Fiberglass-Absorbers-min.pdf" target="_blank">Quilted Fiberglass Absorbers</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-022-Sound-Absorption-Baffles-Wall-Panels-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Sound Absorption Baffles &amp; Wall Panels</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-023-Barrier-Quilted-Fiberglass-Absorber-Composites-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Barrier &amp; Quilted Fiberglass Absorber Composites</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-024-Ultra-Sound-Absorption-Baffles-Wall-Panels.pdf" target="_blank">Ultra Sound Absorption Baffles &amp; Wall Panels</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-025-Sound-Damp-E-Asphalt.pdf" target="_blank">Soundamp E Asphalt Based Vibration Damping Sheets</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-026-Ceiling-Clouds.pdf" target="_blank">Ceiling Clouds</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-026-Sailcloth-Baffles.pdf" target="_blank">Sailcloth Baffles</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-027-Barricade-Banners.pdf" target="_blank">Barricade Banners</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-037-Aluminum-Lagging-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Aluminum Lagging</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Roll-Up Doors</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/RD-006-G2-3600-FAB-Sheet-min.pdf" target="_blank">G2 Model 3600 Features</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/RD-007-G2-5400-FAB-Sheet-min.pdf" target="_blank">G2 Model 5400 Features</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Replacement-of-G2-Panels-and-Pulltrusions.pdf" target="_blank">Replacement of G2 Panels and Pultrusions</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Shavers-Side-Seal-Bug-Curtain-Insturctions.pdf" target="_blank">Side Seal Bug Curtain Installation Instructions</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/RD-010-G2-1800-Series-Face-Mount.pdf" target="_blank">G2 1800 Series - Face Mount</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>PVC Strip Curtains</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-011-Truck-Curtain-Drawing.pdf" target="_blank">PVC Strip Curtain - Truck Installation Drawing</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-012-Truck-Curtain-Installation-Instructions.pdf" target="_blank">PVC Strip Curtain - Truck Installation Instructions</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Miscellaneous</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TD-001-Certificate-of-compliance-Food.pdf" target="_blank">Certificate of Compliance - International Food Safety Standards</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TD-003-Fabric-Specifications.pdf" target="_blank">Fabric Specifications</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What is it that you are clicking on that causes the behavior you don't like and what is supposed to happen when it is clicked?

Comment: for `e.currentTarget.className += " active";` you're always applying a class to the current clicked link without removing previous ones. All you need to do before this is remove the active class from all links before running this line of code.

Comment: For example, now I have 3 tags they are in grey right now. When I click the first, it changes into red, but when I click the second tag, this tag also changes to red, however the first tag is still in red. I don't want them in red at the same time. Can I color the tag that I click on with other tags not colored? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we add a loop in your show function that removes the `active` class from each of the tabs, the problem is solved.

Additionally, I have updated your code to remove the inline HTML event handling attributes and instead am using the modern and standards-compliant `addEventListener()` API.

Lastly, I have removed the `href="javascript:void(0)"` code from each tab as `<li>` elements do not get the `href` attribute in the first place.

You will note how much cleaner that section of the HTML is now that we have separated the JavaScript from the HTML.

```js
// Get a reference to the tabs
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".rcTab");

// Loop through them and assign click event handlers to them
tabs.forEach(function(tab, index){
  tab.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    show(e, "rcContent" + (index + 1));
  });
});

function show(e, n) {

  
// Loop through the tabs and remove the active class from all of them
tabs.forEach(function(tab, index){
  tab.classList.remove("active");
});
// *******************************************************************
  
     var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    
        // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("rcContent");
  
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    
        // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
    
        // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
        document.getElementById(n).style.display = "block";
        e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
    }
```

```css
.rcTab{
     list-style: none;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 2px 8px;
     margin: 0 5px;
     background: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 2px;
     background-color: #aaa;
     color: white;
    }
    .rcTab:hover{
     background-color:#cd2027;
    }
    
    .rcTab.active {
     background-color: #cd2027; /*url("http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/themes/shaver/img/bkg-redlines.png");*/
    
    }
    .rcContent {
     display: none;
    }
    
    .rcContent h4 {
     //transform: translate(50%, 0);
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .rc {
     list-style-image: url('http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/document-e1481910868320.png');
     background: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     margin-left: 40px
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="rcTabs" id="Tabs">
     <li class="rcTab active">Literature</li>
     <li class="rcTab">Case Studies</li>
     <li class="rcTab">Technical Data Sheets</li>
    </ul>
    <div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 10px 5px;">
    <div id="rcContent1" class="rcContent" style="display: block;">
    <h4>Curtains &amp; Dividers</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Curtain-Walls-General-web1.pdf">Curtains &amp; Dividers Brochure</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SW-C100Curtain-Wall-Auto-.pdf">Curtain Wall - Automative</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Curtain-vs.-Perm.-Wall-.pdf">Curtain Wall vs. Permanent Wall</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SW-I200InsulWall-Brochure-WEB.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall Brochure</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Building-Green-InsulWall.pdf" target="_blank">Green InsulWall</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Roll-Up Doors</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/G2-Lite-Doors-NEW-o.pdf">G2 Lite Series</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/G2-5400-Series-NEW-o.pdf">G2 5400 Series</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>PVC Strip Curtains</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-010-Truck-Strip-Curtains.pdf" target="_blank">Rear PVC Strip Door System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Noise Control Solutions</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-001-Compressor-Enclosure-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Compressor Enclosure</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Welding Protection</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Swing Doors</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SD-001-400-Series-Swing-Door.pdf" target="_blank">400 Series Swing Door</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SD-002-700-Series-Swing-Door.pdf" target="_blank">700 Series Swing Door</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SD-003-1000-Series-Swing-Door.pdf" target="_blank">1000 Series Swing Door</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Truck Curtains, Insulated Bulkheads &amp; Dividers</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-001-BH200-Bulkheads.pdf" target="_blank">High Performance BH2000 Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-002-Light-Weight-CoolGaurd.pdf" target="_blank">Lightweight Series CoolGuard Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-003-Delivery-Van-Bulkhead.pdf" target="_blank">Delivery Van Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-004-VersaFit-Bulkhead.pdf" target="_blank">VersaFit Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-005-Z-Shape-Bulkhead.pdf" target="_blank">Z-Shaped Bulkhead</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-007-Quick-Release-Truck-Curtain.pdf" target="_blank">Quick Release Rear Door Curtain</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-008-Roller-Curtain.pdf" target="_blank">Rear Roller Curtain</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-009-Gravity-Door-Curtain.pdf" target="_blank">Side Door Gravity Curtain</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-010-Truck-Strip-Curtains.pdf" target="_blank">Rear PVC Strip Door System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-006-Center-Divide-System.pdf" target="_blank">Center Divide System</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rcContent2" class="rcContent">
    <h4></h4>
    <h4>Curtains &amp; Dividers</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/whats-behind-your-curtain-wall/" target="_blank">What’s Behind Your Curtain Wall?</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/facility-operations-wall/" target="_blank">Facility Operations: More Than a Wall</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-custom-curtains-protect-print-press-from-dust-and-debris/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Custom Curtains Protect Print Press From Dust and Debris</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Insulated Curtains (InsulWall)</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SW-I900-InsulWall-Beer-CS-Press.pdf" target="_blank">Beer Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Berries-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Berries Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Cheese-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Cheese Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Chocolate-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Chocolate Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Data-Center-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Date Centre Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Farm-Fresh-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Farm Fresh Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Floral-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Floral Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/SW-1800-InsullWall-Ice-Cream-CS-.pdf" target="_blank">Ice Cream Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-M-Block-CS-Low-Res.pdf" target="_blank">M Block Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Pharma-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Pharma Case Study</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/InsulWall-Red-Bull-CS-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Red Bull Case Study</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Noise Control Solutions</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/employee-air-conditioning-booth/" target="_blank">Employee Air Conditioning Booth</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/enclose-noisy-equipment-factory/" target="_blank">Enclose Noisy Equipment in Your Factory</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/noise-solutions-for-roof-top-hvac-units/" target="_blank">Noise Solutions For Roof Top HVAC Units</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/compressor-enclosure-for-automotive/" target="_blank">Compressor Enclosure for Automotive Dealership</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-sound-panels-work-wonders-at-stamping-plant/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Sound Panels Work Wonders at Stamping Plant</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-enclosures-reduce-compressor-noise-automotive-facility/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Enclosures Reduce Compressor Noise In Automotive Facility</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/noisy-plastic-regrind-machine-no-match-for-shavers-custom-enclosure-system/" target="_blank">Noisy Plastic Regrind Machine No Match for Shaver’s Custom Enclosure System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/noisy-compressors-no-match-for-shavers-sound-absorber-panels/" target="_blank">Noisy Compressors No Match for Shaver’s Sound Absorber Panels</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-power-roll-up-door-contains-noise-from-parts-being-dumped-into-a-hopper/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Power Roll Up Door Contains Noise From Parts Being Dumped Into a Hopper</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shavers-noise-abatement-solutions-increase-productivity-and-safety/" target="_blank">Shaver’s Noise Abatement Solutions Increase Productivity and Safety</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/shaver-helps-mining-company-increase-productivity/" target="_blank">Shaver Helps Mining Company Increase Productivity</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/power-roll-up-doors-for-food-handling-industry/" target="_blank">Power Roll Up Doors for Food Handling Industry</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-029-Case-Study-Acoustical-Curtain-Panel.pdf" target="_blank">Squealing Tires and Screeching Tires</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-030-Case-Study-Acoustical-Curtain-Panels.pdf" target="_blank">Outdoor Noise Solution</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-033-Case-Study-Acoustical-Lagging.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Lagging Quiets Perkins School For The Blind</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-034-Case-Study-Accoustical-Absorption-Barrier-Panels.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Composite Quiets Compressor Station</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-035-Case-Study-BSC-25-Absorber-Barrier-Composite.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-25 Absorber Used in Portland Meseum of Art</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-036-Case-Study-Acoustical-Lagging.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Lagging Quiets Airport HVAC System</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rcContent3" class="rcContent">
    <h4></h4>
    <h4>Track System &amp; Mounting Information</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Pan-Ceiling-Mount.pdf" target="_blank"> Pan Ceiling Mount</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Roll-TracR-Hardware-MASTER-PDF-min-1.pdf" target="_blank">Track Mounting System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Hardware-Industrial-Curtain2.pdf" target="_blank">Track Hardware Overview</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Roller-Track-Installation-Instructions1.pdf" target="_blank">Roller Track Installation Instructions</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Curtains &amp; Dividers</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/CD-001Curtain-Wall-vs.-Perm-Wall1.pdf" target="_blank">Curtain Wall Vs. Permanent Wall</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-018-R3-InsulWall-Spec.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall R3 Spec Sheet</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-018-R3-InsulWall-Spec.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall R6 Spec Sheet</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-020-R9-InsulWall-Spec.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall R9 Spec Sheet</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-021-R15-InsulWall-Spec.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall R15 Spec Sheet</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/IW-014-InsulWall-Green-Specs-Print-20162.pdf" target="_blank">InsulWall Green Spec Sheet</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Noise Control Solutions</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-004-BBC10.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-10 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-005-BBC13-revised.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-13 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-006-BBC13-2in.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-13-2" Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-007-BBC15.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-15 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-008-BBC15-2in.pdf" target="_blank">BBC-15-2" Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-009-BSC19.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-19 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-010-BSC22.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-22 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-011-BSC24.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-24 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite&gt;/a&gt;</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-012-BSC25.pdf" target="_blank">BSC-25 Noise Barrier/Sound Absorber Composite</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-013-QFA1-.pdf" target="_blank">QFA-1 Quilted Fiberglass Absorber</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-014-QFA7.pdf" target="_blank">QFA-7 Quilted Fiberglass Absorber</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-015-QFA10.pdf" target="_blank">QFA-10 Quilted Fiberglass Absorber</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-016-QFA14.pdf" target="_blank">QFA-14 Quilted Fiberglass Absorber</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-017-Acoustical-Curtain-Systems-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Curtain Systems</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-018-Curtain-Track-Systems-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Curtain Track System</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-019-Flexible-Noise-Barriers.pdf" target="_blank">Flexible Noise Barrier</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-020-Acoustical-Pipe-Duct-Lagging-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Acoustical Pipe &amp; Duct Lagging</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-021-Quilted-Fiberglass-Absorbers-min.pdf" target="_blank">Quilted Fiberglass Absorbers</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-022-Sound-Absorption-Baffles-Wall-Panels-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Sound Absorption Baffles &amp; Wall Panels</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-023-Barrier-Quilted-Fiberglass-Absorber-Composites-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Barrier &amp; Quilted Fiberglass Absorber Composites</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-024-Ultra-Sound-Absorption-Baffles-Wall-Panels.pdf" target="_blank">Ultra Sound Absorption Baffles &amp; Wall Panels</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-025-Sound-Damp-E-Asphalt.pdf" target="_blank">Soundamp E Asphalt Based Vibration Damping Sheets</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-026-Ceiling-Clouds.pdf" target="_blank">Ceiling Clouds</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-026-Sailcloth-Baffles.pdf" target="_blank">Sailcloth Baffles</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-027-Barricade-Banners.pdf" target="_blank">Barricade Banners</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/NA-037-Aluminum-Lagging-Web.pdf" target="_blank">Aluminum Lagging</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Roll-Up Doors</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/RD-006-G2-3600-FAB-Sheet-min.pdf" target="_blank">G2 Model 3600 Features</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/RD-007-G2-5400-FAB-Sheet-min.pdf" target="_blank">G2 Model 5400 Features</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Replacement-of-G2-Panels-and-Pulltrusions.pdf" target="_blank">Replacement of G2 Panels and Pultrusions</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/Shavers-Side-Seal-Bug-Curtain-Insturctions.pdf" target="_blank">Side Seal Bug Curtain Installation Instructions</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/RD-010-G2-1800-Series-Face-Mount.pdf" target="_blank">G2 1800 Series - Face Mount</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>PVC Strip Curtains</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-011-Truck-Curtain-Drawing.pdf" target="_blank">PVC Strip Curtain - Truck Installation Drawing</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TL-012-Truck-Curtain-Installation-Instructions.pdf" target="_blank">PVC Strip Curtain - Truck Installation Instructions</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>Miscellaneous</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TD-001-Certificate-of-compliance-Food.pdf" target="_blank">Certificate of Compliance - International Food Safety Standards</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/wp-content/uploads/TD-003-Fabric-Specifications.pdf" target="_blank">Fabric Specifications</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
    <ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
    <ul>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
     <li class="rc"><a href="website" target="_blank">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But when I copy your code on my website, it seems not working, here is the link, if you can have a look at this.

Comment: http://www.shaverinc.com/resource-centre/?preview=true&preview_id=2383&preview_nonce=89af3f2a7e

Comment: I cannot access your site, but more importantly, if it's not working, it's got to be something else because, as you can see, it works.

Answer (score 0):

replace tablinks with rcTab in this part

```
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
```

into

```
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("rcTab");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
```

as shown here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygKmxb